# Overwriting wget output to a text file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, sh, wget

I'm trying to write `wget` command's filtered output to a file, but it always appends to the text file and display some unrecognizable characters.

Following script will output on CLI like 1% , 2% and so on nicely but when I redirect the output to a text file, it shows some wired characters and all get appended instead of getting overwritten.

```
#!/bin/sh
download()
{
    local url=$1
    wget --progress=dot $url 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
        sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
    echo " DONE"
}

file="$1"
echo -n "Downloading $file:"
download "$file" > file.log
```

I tried using `>` won't work, where am I doing wrong?

This is what I found on the file.

```
  1%  2%  3%  5%  6%  7%  9% 9% 10% 11% 13% 13% 13% 14%
```

but it should be

```
14%
```

Just the current progress.

All I'm trying to do is write current file progress ( like `10%` ) so I can just read the file and check file progress regularly for fronted purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` (and many other command line tools) use shell escape sequences to display their progress.

This means they print "0%", then do something, then tell the terminal "overwrite '0%' with '5%'", etc.

When you redirect the output to a file, you see these "overwrite" codes.

Using `--progress=dot` should solve this; then you don't see any percentages (nor any erase code). Instead, it will print one dot per 1K downloaded and you have to count dots.